# I am querying for the author with particular '_id' but it displaying the all authors [Graphql]

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have defined Author as below:

```
const Author = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Author',
  description: 'Represent the type of an author of a blog post or a comment',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: {type: GraphQLString},
    name: {type: GraphQLString},
    posts: {type: Post}
  })
});
```

I have defined my Query as below

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Root_Query",
  fields: {
    authors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(Author),
      args: {_id: { type: GraphQLString },name:{type: GraphQLString}}, 
      resolve: function(rootValue, args, info) {
        let fields = {};
        let fieldASTs = info.fieldASTs;
        fieldASTs[0].selectionSet.selections.map(function(selection) {
          fields[selection.name.value] = 1;
        });
        return authorsCollection.find({}, fields).toArray();
      }
    }
```

Now when I query for author with particular id by using the query given below

```
{
  authors(_id: "57c5794a92aef65040c4e0e6"){
    _id
    name
  }
}
```

Instead of displaying author with `_id` `57c5794a92aef65040c4e0e6` .It is displaying all the authors `_id` and `name`. How can I solve the problem??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the following DB code, which fetches all authors because of empty query `{}`:

```
return authorsCollection.find({}, fields).toArray()
```

Add `_id` to your query:

```
// import {ObjectID} from 'mongodb';
const authorId = ObjectID.createFromHexString(args._id);
return authorsCollection.find({_id: authorId}, fields).toArray()
```

You have to